# MAX aggregate function principle in long to wide table transform

Tags: sql, postgresql, max, aggregate-functions

https://dbfiddle.uk/Y2h4mq4X

It is an example where data table is tranforming from long to wide format. I have a question of principle of MAX aggregate function there. How does it work?

Comment: Creating a DBFiddle may be helpful when asking a question but should not be required in order for someone to understand your question. Please update your question with enough information (as editable text) so that someone can understand what you are asking. I assume you have read the documentation for this function so what is the specific issue that you don't understand or was not covered by the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Run your query **without** specifying GROUP BY and MAX(). With this you can visualize how those operations and functions transform your results. Try: (see [Demo Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/2TdiEk2a))

```
  SELECT id2, 
    CASE WHEN key = 3 THEN value END AS a3,
    CASE WHEN key = 7 THEN value END AS a7,
    CASE WHEN key = 101 THEN value END AS a101,
    CASE WHEN key = 102 THEN value END AS a102,
    CASE WHEN key = 133 THEN value END AS a133,
    CASE WHEN key = 140 THEN value END AS a140,
    CASE WHEN key = 239 THEN value END AS a239,
    CASE WHEN key = 250 THEN value END AS a250
FROM tmp
order by id2;
```